Python - how to use CRT and key file in requests
I am using the requests library in Python. The API request works fine in Postman after adding the certificate and key.
Here is my code:
import requests
import json

url= ""

cert_path = ""
key_path = ""

try:
    payload = {"key": "val"}
    headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}

    response = requests.request('POST',url, data=json.dumps(payload),headers=headers, cert=(cert_path,key_path))

    print("Response status code:", response.status_code)
    print("Response content:", response.text)

except Exception as err:
    print(f"An error occurred: {err}")


I am facing the following error:
SSL error occurred: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /b2b/login (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(398, '[SSL: CA_MD_TOO_WEAK] ca md too weak (_ssl.c:3874)')))

Help me how to resolve this.

The CA certificate uses and outdated algorithm. The OpenSSL libs linked to your Python versions do not accept it anymore. While you could use an older version or possibly reconfigure OpenSSL the long term fix would be to issue new certificates.

what - downgrade libs due to a certificate that is likely outside the control of the party developing the code? That approach makes absolutely no sense. It is possible to add the target domain to an allow list, or temporarily ignore the certificates for this connection alone - that is the thing to do.

@jsbueno "temporarily ignore the certificates for this connection alone - that is the thing to do." The worst of all possible solutions.
